# PHP Replace tags / placeholders / markers in text string with dynamic values

Tags: php, arrays, variables, replace

Basically, what I want to achieve is dynamically replace `{SOME_TAG}` with "Text".
My idea was to read all tags like `{SOME_TAG}`, put them into array.
Then convert array keys into variables like `$some_tag`, and put them into array.

So, this is how far I got:

```
//Some code goes here
$some_tag = "Is defined somewhere else.";
$different_tag = 1 + $something;
Some text {SOME_TAG} appears in different file, which contents has been read earlier.
//Some code goes here 

preg_match_all('/{\w+}/', $strings, $search);
$search = str_replace(str_split('{}'),"",$search[0]);
$search = array_change_key_case( array_flip($search), CASE_LOWER);
...some code missing here, which I cant figure out.
```

Replace array should look something like this

```
$replace = array($some_tag, $different_tag);
//Then comes replacing code and output blah blah blah..
```

How to make array `$replace` contain variables dynamically depending on `$search` array?

Comment: That did not make sense.

Comment: How do you want us to help.. Please edit your question properly so that others can understand. Also please do not try to copy paste code. You should not say "..Some code missing here, which i cant figure out"? what does this mean ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not something along the lines of:

```
<?php

$replace = array(
  '{TAG_1}' => 'hello',
  '{TAG_2}' => 'world',
  '{TAG_3}' => '!'
);

$myString = '{TAG_1} {TAG_2}{TAG_3}{TAG_3}';

echo str_replace(array_keys($replace), array_values($replace), $myString);
```

Comment: In the beginning it was my first idea too. Looks like this will work better. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly:

You're working on trying to create a customizable document, using {TAGS} in order to represent replaceable areas that can be filled in with dynamic information.  At some point in time while replacing the {TAGS} with the dynamic information, you want the dynamic information to be stored in automatically generated basic variable names, as $tags.

I'm not sure why you want to convert these tags to basic variables instead using them entirely as array keys.  I would like to point out that this represents a security or functionality hole - what happens if someone puts {REPLACE} in as a tag in your document?  Your replace array would get overwritten with dynamic data, and your whole program would fall apart.  Either that, or the whole replace array would get dumped in for {REPLACE}, making for a very messy document with perhaps data you don't WANT them to have in it.  Perhaps you have this dealt with - I don't have all the context here - but I thought I'd point out the risk factor.

As for a better solution, unless there's some specific need that you're addressing by going through $tags instead of using using the $replace array directly, I like @Emissary's answer.